trying to test an ESM module with jasmine-browser-runner
I was using jasmine to run my specs which both my test & source code used import statements...  However, the last thing I had added to my real-world code was something involving window.location ...  Jasmine threw an error saying "window is undefined"
After looking around online, it looks like I need to be using jasmine-browser-runner as I could not find any way to simply define an empty window object for my specs (is there any way to do this?) ...  So I installed jasmine-browser-runner and as soon as I run it, now I get:
Suite error: undefined
  Message:
    Cannot use import statement outside a module
  Stack:
    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
  Message:
    Cannot use import statement outside a module
  Stack:
    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
  Message:
    Unexpected token 'export'
  Stack:
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
  Message:
    Cannot use import statement outside a module

So, I can't use window with jasmine, and I can't use import or export with jasmine-browser-runner???
